# Uncaught SyntaxError: when make ajax call to the controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My controller action method:

```
// GET: 
public ActionResult Index(Guid id, string name)
{
```

In the view, I make an ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Languages").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/MyController/Index",
            datatype: "text",
            data: { id: '@Model.Guid', name: value  },
            type: "GET",
            success: function () {
                console.log('Success')
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
    });
```

But I get the error in chrome debugger.
      Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

My questions:

1) How to fix it?
2) Use 'POST' or 'GET'?

Comment: Indent your code correctly and it would be obvious :)

Comment: Shamed. Good coding habit needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
});
```

You forgot the statement above. Insert it at the end of your script :)

Comment: I use GET but  I get 500 error. Should I use `POST`?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError mean that your javascript code is syntactically incorrect. The call on server should not even happend, and there is no reason to talk about GET or POST.

PS: if you just retrieve some data, you'd better use GET